# Discover different lines across similar files

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a text file with many tens of thousands short sentences like this:

```
go to venice
come back from grece
new york here i come
from belgium to russia and back to spain
```

I run a tagging algorithm which produces a tagged output of this sentence file:

```
go to <place>venice</place>
come back from <place>grece</place>
<place>new york</place> here i come
from <place>belgium</place> to <place>russia</place> and back to <place>spain</place>
```

The algorithm runs over the input multiple times and produces each time slightly different tagging. My goal is to identify those lines where those differences occur. In other words, print all utterances for which the tagging differs across N results files.

For example N=10, I get 10 tagged files. Suppose line 1 is tagged all the time the same for all 10 tagged files - do not print it. Suppose line 2 is tagged once this way and 9 times other way - print it. And so on.

For N=2 is easy, I just run diff. But what to do if I have N=10 results?

Comment: would iterating over diff be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the tagged files - just create a counter for each line of how many times you've seen it:

```
# use defaultdict for convenience
from collections import defaultdict

# start counting at 0
counter_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

tagged_file_names = ['tagged1.txt', 'tagged2.txt', ...]

# add all lines of each file to dict
for file_name in tagged_file_names:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        # use enumerate to maintain order
        # produces (LINE_NUMBER, LINE CONTENT) tuples (hashable)
        for line_with_number in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            counter_dict[line_with_number] += 1

# print all values that do not repeat in all files (in same location)
for key, value in counter_dict.iteritems():
    if value < len(tagged_file_names):
        print "line number %d: [%s] only repeated %d times" % (
            key[0], key[1].strip(), value
        )
```

**Walkthrough:**

First of all, we create a data structure to enable us counting our entries, which are numbered lines. This data structure is a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which a default value of `0` - which is the count of newly added lines (increased to 1 with each add).

Then, we create the actual entry using a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) which is **hashable**, so it can be used as a dictionary key, and by default **deeply-comparable** to other tuples. this means `(1, "lolz")` is equal to `(1, "lolz")` but different than `(1, "not lolz")` or `(2, lolz)` - so it fits our use of deep-comparing lines to account for content as well as position.

Now all that's left to do is add all entries using a straightforward `for` loop and see what keys (which correspond to numbered lines) appear in all files (that is - their value is equal to the number of tagged files provided).

**Example:**

```
reut@tHP-EliteBook-8470p:~/python/counter$ cat tagged1.txt 
123
abc
def
reut@tHP-EliteBook-8470p:~/python/counter$ cat tagged2.txt 
123
def
def
reut@tHP-EliteBook-8470p:~/python/counter$ ./difference_counter.py 
line number 1: [abc] only repeated 1 times
line number 1: [def] only repeated 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

if you compare all of them to the first text, then you can get a list of all texts that are different. this might not be the quickest way but it would work.

```
import difflib
n1 = '1 2 3 4 5 6'
n2 = '1 2 3 4 5 6'
n3 = '1 2 4 5 6 7'
l = [n1, n2, n3]
m = [x for x in l if x != l[0]]
diff = difflib.unified_diff(l[0], l.index(m))
print ''.join(diff)
```